# issues with select() statements

Tags: c, sockets, unix-socket

I have a program that is using select() to poll for a socket ready to be connected.

I have another program that binds to a socket and issues send() commands.

The question I have is if the file descriptors work across two executables like that.

i.e. if I add file descriptor 5  in program A to the FD_SET, and my socket fd in program B is 5, does this mean that send() on that socket will wake up program A that is doing a select on the FD_SET containing 5?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, file descriptor numbers are process-specific. Using the same fd number across different processes has no implicit effect.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with file descriptor numbers.

If you send via a socket over a connection whose other end is a socket that is being selected on for reads, the selector will detect the read event.

Comment: Ah - ok. I was under the impression that the set of descriptors that a select statement looks after was static across all processes. I will double check that my socket being created is the same on both sides.

Comment: @Derek That impression doesn't even make sense. FDs are local to a process.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly 1024 descriptors (file/ socket) were supported by a given process (0-1023) (See the max limit of file/ socket descriptor supported by process in /proc//limits).

First 3 descriptors (0, 1 and 2) were assigned to stdin, stdout and stderr respectively. The next
descriptor with value 3 will be assigned to the next open file / socket descriptors and can go till the limit specified in /proc. Note: You can also change the max supported descriptor.

You can see the list of file descriptors open by a given process in /proc//fd.
Each process descriptor / signal / event scope is specific to process only.

Comment: Thanks - my next question was going to be to see how to find out which fd's a process had open, because I seem to be having an issue where processA is listening indefinitely for a socket to be ready that's never making it

Comment: For easier debugging, in addition to manually walking through `/proc/fd`, you can also try `lsof`.